# Can I use an URL parameter as input for Paypal button text?

Tags: web, url, paypal, parameters

I am trying to build my very first website. I do not have a lot of experience and need some help with PayPal buttons.

My website is created on Wordpress using Elementor.
I have a PayPal button on a page where there is a parameter available in the URL, something like:

www.mywebsite.com/page/?your-email=name.surname@mail.com

The parameter "your-email" is sent from an input form.
I want this email filled in the Paypal button text.

I created a PayPal button on the PayPal website and received following code:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Text">Text</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/BE/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/nl_NL/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I want to automatically fill the e-mail parameter from the URL in the text field.
Is there a way I can alter the PayPal button to take the value "name.surname@mail.com" from the URL and fill it in Text field?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some Javascript to your website that will do this.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.querySelector('input[name="os0"]').value = getUrlParameter('your-email');
});
</script>
```

I tried this in a flat HTML file and it works with your button code, so in theory it should work on your site if placed somewhere that accepts Javascript.